# Get the first element in a list with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables

I currently have a list of elements (which are texts) and I am trying to get the first element of this list containing the word `"stars"`. I tried this (among several other things) but it does not work and i'm quite lost.

The name of the list is name_box :

```
i = 0
for element in name_box:
    if "stars" in element:
        note_finale = element
        print(note_finale)
        break
    else:
        i = i+1
```

(I'm quite new at coding so feel free to give me any tips)

Comment: Can you post the contents of `name_box`?

Comment: Note that you don't need the `i` variable here. The `for` loop does the iteration.

Comment: Thanks ! Here is the content  extract.
[<span class="a-icon-alt">Facebook</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">Twitter</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">Pinterest</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">Free Shipping for Prime Members</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">4.5 out of 5 stars</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">Back</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">4.4 out of 5 stars</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">Prime</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">4.6 out of 5 stars</span>]

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use a generator for this:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'stars', 'starstruck', 'd', 'e', 'f']

res = next(i for i in lst if 'stars' in i)

# 'stars'
```

**Explanation**

- The generator expression cycles through each element until it reaches one which contains "stars". It then returns this element *when called to do so*...
- `next` is a built-in function which retrieves the next item of an iterator.

Comment: I see, thansk a lot !
The format of my list is more or less the following : . [<span class="a-icon-alt">Facebook</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">Twitter</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">Pinterest</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">Free Shipping for Prime Members</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">4.5 out of 5 stars</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">Back</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">4.4 out of 5 stars</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">Prime</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">4.6 out of 5 stars</span>]. and i'd like to get the first item with "stars" in it.

Comment: @LouisVannereau  don't understand your comment. This code will give you the first string containing "stars".

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do this, an example:

```
name_box = ['<span class="a-icon-alt">Facebook</span>', 
            '<span class="a-icon-alt">Twitter</span>', 
            '<span class="a-icon-alt">Pinterest</span>', 
            '<span class="a-icon-alt">Free Shipping for Prime Members</span>', 
            '<span class="a-icon-alt">4.5 out of 5 stars</span>', 
            '<span class="a-icon-alt">Back</span>', 
            '<span class="a-icon-alt">4.4 out of 5 stars</span>', 
            '<span class="a-icon-alt">Prime</span>', 
            '<span class="a-icon-alt">4.6 out of 5 stars</span>']

for e in name_box:
    if 'stars' in e:
        print(e)
```

Note: I had to put `''` around the strings in the list, as the input data you provided these were missing.

Output:

```
<span class="a-icon-alt">4.5 out of 5 stars</span>
<span class="a-icon-alt">4.4 out of 5 stars</span>
<span class="a-icon-alt">4.6 out of 5 stars</span>
```

if you really want to break at first `stars` you can put a `break` statement in, example:

```
for e in name_box:
    if 'stars' in e:
        print(e)
        break
```

[EDIT based on comment]

> when i print my name_box, those ' are indeed missing

It could be that your `name_box` is really a string, not a list. So you need to `split()` to make it a list, example:

```
name_box_string = '[<span class="a-icon-alt">Facebook</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">Twitter</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">Pinterest</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">Free Shipping for Prime Members</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">4.5 out of 5 stars</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">Back</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">4.4 out of 5 stars</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">Prime</span>, <span class="a-icon-alt">4.6 out of 5 stars</span>]'

name_box_list = name_box_string[1:-1].split(',')

for e in name_box_list:
    if 'stars' in e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks for you time Edwin !
IT still does not work but i think that i have an idea : when i print my name_box, those ' are indeed missing. Should i conclude that name_box is not a real list?